# SQL: two queries for different time periods, and calculate percentage change?

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I am using BigQuery and have a table with three columsn: `district` (string), `price` (float) and `timestamp`). My table looks like this:

```
district    price    date
OOX         200      2015-01-01
00Y         213      2015-01-01
00X         215      2015-01-01
```

I want to calculate the mean price by district in 2005, the mean price by district in 2015, and the percentage difference between them. In other words, I'd like output that looks like this:

```
district   price_2005  price_2015  percent_change
00X        125         205         0.64
00Y        116         200         0.72
```

The format of the `percent_change` column isn't critical - it could also be a percentage number, etc.

How can I use BigQuery to do this? I've got this far:

```
SELECT district, AVG(price) AS price 
FROM mytable
WHERE date BETWEEN TIMESTAMP('2005-01-01') AND TIMESTAMP('2015-12-31')
GROUP BY district
```

But I don't know how to get the remaining two columns without doing separate queries. Do I need a subquery?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using conditional aggregation.  Using the legacy SQL interface:

```
select district,
       avg(case when year(date) = 2005 then price end) as price_2005,
       avg(case when year(date) = 2015 then price end) as price_2015,
       ((avg(case when year(date) = 2015 then price end) /
         avg(case when year(date) = 2005 then price end)
        ) - 1) as change
from t
group by district;
```

The idea is the same for the updated SQL interface, but the function for extracting the year is different.